# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, tabs, classcastexception, fragmentpageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I get this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment` when I try to open my activity `CuteCollection.java` in my app. The strange part is that when I click on the first line `(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:122)` in the logcat error, it shows me a line from a file in the `v4.support` library. I cannot edit that code, so there must be something in my code I can change.

To get to this activity, I click a button in my `HomeFragment.java` fragment, which is a fragment in my navigation drawer, which also has the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` extension, just like all items do in my navigation drawer.

I think it might be something to do with my `FragmentPagerAdpater`. Although I did change all of my `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, but still the same error.

UPDATE: When I click on the first line in the `support.v4` library, called `FragmentPagerAdapter`, it brings up that class and shows `Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;` highlighted, which is part of this method (although I can't edit this, since it's from Android):

```
@Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
                fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            }
            mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }
```

Any tips or advice? Thanks.

**CuteCollectionFragment.java**

```
    package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;

import org.azurespot.R;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 1/26/15.
 */
public class CuteCollection extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int PHOTO_TAB = 0;
    private static final int VIDEO_TAB = 1;
    private static final int AUDIO_TAB = 2;
    private static final int TEXT_TAB = 3;

    PhotoTab photoTab;
    TextTab textTab;
    VideoTab videoTab;
    AudioTab audioTab;


    public CuteCollection(){}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_cute_collection);

        // Instantiate tabs
        photoTab = new PhotoTab();
        textTab = new TextTab();
        videoTab = new VideoTab();
        audioTab = new AudioTab();

        // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)
                                            findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    private class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * @return the number of pages (tabs) to display
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Photos";
                case 1:
                    return "Videos";
                case 2:
                    return "Sounds";
                case 3:
                    return "Poems";
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * @return true if the value returned from
         *         {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)} is the same object
         *         as the {@link View} added to the {@link ViewPager}.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return o == view;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch(position){
                case PHOTO_TAB:
                    Bundle photoBundle = new Bundle();
                    photoBundle.putInt("page_position", position + 1);
                    PhotoTab pt = new PhotoTab();
                    pt.setArguments(photoBundle);
                    return pt;
                case VIDEO_TAB :
                    Bundle videoBundle = new Bundle();
                    videoBundle.putInt("page_position", position + 1);
                    VideoTab vt = new VideoTab();
                    vt.setArguments(videoBundle);
                    return new VideoTab();
                case AUDIO_TAB:
                    Bundle audioBundle = new Bundle();
                    audioBundle.putInt("page_position", position + 1);
                    AudioTab at = new AudioTab();
                    at.setArguments(audioBundle);
                    return new AudioTab();
                case TEXT_TAB:
                    Bundle textBundle = new Bundle();
                    textBundle.putInt("page_position", position + 1);
                    TextTab tt = new TextTab();
                    tt.setArguments(textBundle);
                    return new TextTab();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * Instantiate the {@link View} which should be displayed at
         * {@code position}. Here we inflate a layout from the apps resources
         * and then change the text view to signify the position.
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // Inflate a new layout from our resources

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                    container, false);
            // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
            container.addView(view);

            // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            title.setText(String.valueOf(position));

            // Return the View
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * Destroy the item from the {@link ViewPager}. In our case this is
         * simply removing the {@link View}.
         */
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_cute_collection.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2198bb" >

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        custom:pstsTextColorSelected="#ffffff"
        custom:pstsUnderlineColor="#ffffff"
        custom:pstsIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#2198bb"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
03-07 18:35:42.669    6340-6340/org.azurespot E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.azurespot, PID: 6340
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:122)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1071)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1412)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1270)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6691)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. I think you just want solve your run-time error first. And then handle with your design. For that, I'll post an answer since this is a common error with Fragments, I think.

Comment: I updated my earliest answer on "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" and post another one for you to decide on a working sample and design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code seems to run into trouble unless you fix the Exception error. There is a working sample code from Google, and this is quite similar to your code design and meets your vision. I have tried it, and it works. Link at [SlidingTabsBasic](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) . One warning is that you will have to change your Gradle build file. If you choose this route, then I can post my build file.

Another similar sample on the same webpage is **SlidingTabsColors**, which sounds good since I end up in customizing colors for any GUI I make. The SDKs are possibly available on your local drive if you installed it.
If you decide on this route, just accept it as best answer, and post whatever issues you may come up with. At least, I know the sample code works.

Just to let you know, there is an interesting reading at [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), which meets your vision also, and the code seems simpler than what I recommend above. But...it uses ActionBar.TabListener which is deprecated for Lollipop, API version 21. Your choice...

Comment: Thanks @TOA! I was able to get the Creating Swipe Views with Tabs to work minimally, to just show the tabs, However, they won't show my fragment views. I noticed in the code, they don't use xml, they just show text put into a `TextView` for each tab page. In my app, it's simply a `GridView` for each page, but each fragment of the tab has its own layout that I need to use. Another issue is I need to stylize the tabs, so not sure how. Is there a way you can help me in a chat? (When you get a chance, of course). I also cannot swipe the tabs, only click on them to change them.

Comment: I am glad you're progressing forward, and no longer stuck in a vague xml file error. The project mentioned above (I have used it) works well. I used the project to populate ListViews on the Tabs with multiple columns, and it is swipeable.

Comment: If you have further questions, and it seems so, please simply post it onto Stackoverflow with tags of listview, android-fragments, and Android. This is how we build a community and share info, unlike chatting. I will check. In the meantime, you can select this to be the correct and helpful answer.

Comment: That sounds great. Is there anyway I can see you code? I might be able to learn all I need to know from there. Thanks.

Comment: I would rather not share code only because my app is not yet ready for market and I am keeping it a secret. The above project is good. It is missing UI elements in the Tabs (now that I remember). For that, you can search on how to make UI inside a fragment. And that will require you to make XML layouts.

Comment: @Noni, You may also click on the up-arrow icon next to the posted answer, above the checkmark, if you think it is also helpful, why not, hehe. The reason I am active this year is I want to increase my rep by a lot this year.

Comment: Sure okay. I do appreciate your help, as no one else tried at all! :)

Comment: Thanks Noni. One possible issue that "no one else tried at all" is that your problem is not easy and there's much code to see. Sometimes I myself have to make a decision on which problems to tackle and sometimes I skipped on the ones I cannot even understand the question, even tho I might be knowledgeable at it.

Comment: Yes,  it's true. That's the hard part when you go from beginner to intermediate. There are so many variables involved, it's harder to get help. :( Yet I'm not skilled enough to figure it out on my own, often.

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 different solutions/parts.
Part 1)
In your posted Java file, do this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment ;
```

remove or comment out:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

The reason is you are using **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**. And this is not compatible with your current import **android.app.Fragment**. Also all your imports reference **android.support.v4**, so you know you should do it anyway to be consistent :-)
Unfortunately the compiler does not detect this incompatibility.

Part 2)
Since you're using ActionBarActivity, there may be an issue with the build file or settings. The problem is confirmed by others in Stackoverflow @ [ActionBarActivity cannot resolve a symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316055/actionbaractivity-cannot-resolve-a-symbol) and [Error inflating class from library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652990/error-inflating-class-from-library). I know your error sounds different but I think the problem may be the same. Basically you can check your build gradle file (assuming you're using it):

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2"
}
```

The idea is to use compile "com.android.**support:support-v4**..."

Comment: Thanks, I changed every activity that had `android.app.Fragment` and changed it to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, but this error still occurs. The reason I posted all the details is because I think it's possibly connected to them, and could find nothing on Stack to address my problem, so details are needed. I just don't know what the error could mean otherwise.

Comment: Since it is a run-time error (assuming), can you step through code via debugger and tell us which line of code you're failing? You may update your code, to reduce misunderstandings between us. I'll check.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I've been stuck with trying to get this `PagerSlidingTabStrip` to work for days. I updated my code. I changed some things. I thought it best to take the `CuteCollection.java` out of my navigation drawer, so it could become an `Activity`, not a `Fragment`. I kind of had to in order to be able to use the `getSupportFragmentManager()` which comes from `FragmentActivity` (which is inside of `ActionBarActivity`), which is required of the adapter to hook up the tabs strip to my view. Since the tabs are all fragments. Would love to know what you think, thanks.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code that will cause ClassCastException run-time error. Can you tell which code causes the exception? Another thing, you're using package "com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip", perhaps there is compatibility issue with this package/library.

Comment: If you're still pursuing your code, I am adding a possible issue with your build. I am only referencing Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, I would have but that error was too odd. I checked my Gradle `compile` line and I had that one correct, unless you are referring to another part of Gradle. I have already changed the code though to another slider. Having other problems with that now (as mentioned in one of your answers as a comment).